# CloudKit don't sync relationships

Tags: swift, core-data, cloudkit

#### CloudKit + Core Data

I created two entities

- **Credit Card**

  - Relationship: transactions
- **Transaction**

  - Relationship: creditcard

Configuration: Default is already set "used with CloudKit"

#### Problem

The relationships is not sync. For example, on 1st device

```swift
let creditCard = CreditCard(context: viewContext)
creditCard.name = "First Card"

let firstTransaction = CCTransaction(context: viewContext)
firstTransaction.price = "First Transaction"
firstTransaction.price = 100

creditCard.addToTransactions(firstTransaction)
firstTransaction.creditcard = creditCard

try! viewContext.save()

// Check transactions
print(creditCard.transactions.count) // 1
```

on 2nd device after synced

```swift
@FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \CreditCard.name, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    var creditcards: FetchedResults<CreditCard>

// Check transactions
ForEach(creditcards) { creditcard in 
  Card("")
    .onTapGesture {
      print(creditCard.transactions.count) // will have a value of 0 except the device that records the relationship.
    }
}
```

It looks like the relationship never syncs

#### Data Model

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Relationships can sync between devices.
2. but we cannot actually know when and how the syncing works. maybe in minutes or days. So it's not your code to issue this.
3. And I found the syncing will fail when what ever happened I don't know. Apple does not provide any solution to restore the syncing.